# How to check date from sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have sqlite database table which contacts friend and his contacts with date of birth.I want to ring  Alarm when any date match from database with current date.Please Anyone help me How I do this task.
               Actually I want to Match date 2 time a day daily please suggest me.

I am using this code

```
private void setAlarm(String name,String date)
{
    String[] arrdob =date.split("/");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       //for using this you need to import java.util.Calendar;

    // add minutes to the calendar object
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,Integer.parseInt(arrdob[1]));
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(arrdob[2]));                
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Integer.parseInt(arrdob[0]));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,35);
    System.out.println("1");

    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmintent.putExtra("title","B'Day Alarm");
    alarmintent.putExtra("subject","Hi!Todays "+name+" B'Day");

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), HELLO_ID,
    alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT |  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    //VERY IMPORTANT TO SET FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT... this will send correct extra's informations to 
    //AlarmReceiver Class
   // Get the AlarmManager service               
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
}
```

call this method at when insert value into database.
                                                    AlarmReceiver class is as:

```
private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) //
{
    // NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
    System.out.println("2");
   //context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager)     
    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = 
        new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Combi Note",System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 
            NOTIFICATION_ID, 
            new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);

    Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
    String title=extras.getString("title");
 //here we get the title and description of our Notification
    String note=extras.getString("subject");
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, note, title, contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

//here we set the default sound for our 
//notification

```
    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    manger.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, notification);
}
```

Comment: are you trying to do something like birthday alarm?

Comment: yes,I am trying to set Alarm Manager for each date of birth save in sqlite at time of inserting.

Comment: just compare two dates like : Date firstDate = new Date(); Date secondDate = new Date();firstDate.compareTo(secondDate)

Comment: @Zaz Gmy: when I compare date please suggest me properly.Why setAlarm is not working?

Comment: try this int diff=firstDate.compareTo(secondDate); if(diff==0){notify user}else{date not same}

Comment: perhaps you are not seeing my code I ask only what error in my code,If my way is wrong then what is right way.I have to do only when date match to system date done ringing.